# keytool -importkeystore gives error when using openssl pkcs12 -export with -passout pass:mypw option

Tags: openssl

I'm running `openssl pkcs12 -export` with `-passout pass:123` for automation purpose (without prompt for pw), then using `keytool -importkeystore` to generate `keystore.jks`. It failed to decrypt password with "pass:mypw" option, running `openssl export` without `-passout pass:123` works just fine. But I really need the `-passout pass:mypw` for automation purpose without being prompt for pw.

```
% openssl pkcs12 -export -out keystore.pkcs12 -in mydomain.com_cert.pem \
  -inkey mydomain.com_key.pem -passout pass:123

% keytool -v -importkeystore -srckeystore keystore.pkcs12 -srcstoretype PKCS12 \
  -destkeystore keystore.jks -deststoretype JKS -deststorepass pass:123 \
  -srcstorepass pass:123
```

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `openssl` command:

   I don't see anything wrong, so you have the PKCS12, but you can’t convert it to JKS.
2. `keytool` command:

   You don’t put `pass:` before the `PASSWORD` like in OpenSSL.

   ```
   keytool -v -importkeystore -srckeystore keystore.pkcs12 -srcstoretype PKCS12 -destkeystore keystore.jks -deststoretype JKS -deststorepass 12345678 -srcstorepass 12345678
   ```